# What is the command in Excel VBA to delete a specific macro?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have an Excel Macro Template. I run a macro on it and it saves the new spreadsheet as an xlsx instead.

I'm just wondering if there's a simple command for VBA that just deletes a macro by name.

I've researched this a lot, and there are basically two answers which don't really fit.

The first is to not have macros in the workbook I'm saving and to just run macros from one workbook to another.  (I don't want to do this for a few reasons, but simplicity is the main reason.)

The second is a VBA script that strips ALL VBA and connections from the workbook.  (I don't need it to do that much, and I'd rather just delete the one macro I have.)

So, what I'm looking for is just something like this:

`Delete.Macro("Import")`    'This command deletes the macro in this workbook named "Import".

Comment: there is no simple "Delete this macro" command. This [site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) will help you though. There's a function in there called `DeleteProcedureFromModule`

Comment: Posting your solution as [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) fits the format here much better than editing your question - it will make it easier for anyone else with the same question to find your solution.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Sub main()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False   
Workbooks("PutWorkBookName").SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Fun thought, use VBA to remove VBA... but seems more work than necessary.

What about `activeworkbook.saveas "filename.xlsx", xlExcel12`?

As I am sure you are aware, an .xlsx doesn't have any code, so if you set warnings to false, etc., it will just save the file and delete the code.

Now, if I misread, and you want to delete only some of your code, leave the rest, and save as xlsx... you are out of luck.